# Adding to sub list/array within apex wrapper class

Tags: apex, list, wrapper-class

I am trying to figure out how to add to this wrapper class.

```
public class Invoice {

public String Type;
public LineItem[] LineItems;


public class LineItem {
    public String ItemCode;
    public Decimal LineAmount;  //600

}


}
```

I can initiate the Invoice List easily with

```
  Invoice newInvoice = new Invoice();
```

Then I can add to that list:

```
  newInvoice.Type = 'Sample';
```

However, how the heck do I add the multiple line items in the sub list??? This was my guess, but it's wrong:

```
 newInvoice.LineItem[0].ItemCode = '1234';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create new instance of `LineItem`   first like below since `LineItem`  is a child class of `Invoice` so you have to use `Invoice.LineItem` to initialize the class

```
Invoice.LineItem  lineItem1 = new Invoice.LineItem();
lineItem1.ItemCode = 'item1';
lineItem1.LineAmount = 10;

Invoice.LineItem  lineItem2 = new Invoice.LineItem();
lineItem2.ItemCode = 'item2';
lineItem2.LineAmount = 20;

Invoice.LineItem  lineItem3 = new Invoice.LineItem();
lineItem3.ItemCode = 'item3';
lineItem3.LineAmount = 30;
```

After that create a new instance of Invoice class and after that add into its variables `type` and `LineItem`

```
Invoice newInvoice = new Invoice();
newInvoice.Type = 'Sample';

 newInvoice.LineItems.add(lineItem1 );
 newInvoice.LineItems.add(lineItem2 );
 newInvoice.LineItems.add(lineItem3 );
```

### Updates

You have receive an error because `newInvoice.LineItem` is null at the starting point.

So before adding the item to the list you have initialize the like

```
 Invoice newInvoice = new Invoice();
 newInvoice.Type = 'Sample';
 newInvoice.LineItems = new List<Invoice.LineItem>();
 newInvoice.LineItem.add(lineItem1 );
 newInvoice.LineItem.add(lineItem2 );
 newInvoice.LineItem.add(lineItem3 );
```

Comment: Thanks for that was what I wanted. I found that I hit a null error when adding the line items so I added an empty line like follows before adding them (ugly I know, I don't know what the problem was though:   Invoice.LineItem EmptyLine = new Invoice.LineItem ();
newInvoice.LineItems = new Invoice.LineItem[]{EmptyLine};

Comment: @DanielHowell check the updated answer